# 1989 Nissan pintara problem

Tags: nissan, exhaust, catalytic-converter

I have a 1989 U12 2.4l Nissan Pintara. It started running really rough one day and when I got home the exhaust manifold was glowing red hot. I changed the catalytic converter and it still is running like it was before I changed it, any suggestions please?

I have not been brave enough to drive it long enough to see if exhaust glows red again, but i am pretty sure it will as i only drove it around a couple of streets and it was pretty hot under the hood then.

Comment: You are saying the engine is still running rough, but the manifold is no longer glowing red, or is it?

Answer (score 1):

Other than a lean fuel mix, you may also have a valve train problem - if the exhaust valves are opening too soon or never closing correctly, it'd dump still-burning exhaust into the exhaust manifold. It'd run very poorly and may get your exhaust manifold hot enough to glow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is running lean, which leads to increased exhaust temperatures. Check the fuel pressure and that the injectors are flowing properly.